# Fields of workitem, TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

How to access Fields of workitem like Type, Category, Found in Phase,reproducible, Found in build. I have created a workitem. But I get a error work item is not saved giving All the above mentioned fields are empty. few of those fields are read only. I am not able to write to it. Please someone can help me out soon.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS 2010 set bug work item severity after build failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667039/tfs-2010-set-bug-work-item-severity-after-build-failure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is installing [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f), which provides a Process Template Editor.

Process Template Editor is a Visual Studio add-in, located under the **Tools** menu. The Process Template Editor provides a graphical user interface for customizing work items (field, workflow and the form) and process templates.

[image]